# Difficulty running friedman post hoc test

Tags: r

I am trying to complete a Friedman post-hoc test in R; i am having trouble with every package i have used so far (`PCMR`, `PMCMRplus`, `NSM3`). My response data are ordinal, and I am not sure if that is the problem. Any package or code suggestions that may help?

I have completed a Friedman test analyzing weekly behavior in animals over 24 weeks. behavioral categories include "defensive, "stopping", and "escape" behaviors.

DATA is `0.014ppmgeneralFriedman`

```
head(`0.014ppmgeneralFriedman`)
  crayfishid   group time behavior

Nbehavior <- data_frame(behavior = c("def","stop","escape"))

mapping <- c("def"=1,"stop"=2,"escape"=3)

orderedbehavior <- mapping[`0.014ppmgeneralFriedman`$behavior]

friedman.test(orderedbehavior~time|crayfishid, data=`0.014ppmgeneralFriedman`)

    Friedman rank sum test

data:  orderedbehavior and time and crayfishid
Friedman chi-squared = 44.152, df = 24, p-value = 0.007325
```

I cannot successfully complete post hoc however!

Comment: Maube [this](https://www.r-statistics.com/2010/02/post-hoc-analysis-for-friedmans-test-r-code/) will be of help.

Comment: Also of interest, a [Cross validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175441/friedmans-test-is-very-significant-but-its-post-hoc-comparisons-spss-are-not).

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have recently implemented information from each of these sources without success.